# Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file When testing the application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, dart

[image]In Android Studio the application was running on Real device, it was exported in ABK format .. But after a while, this error appears I read about gradle but didn't understand exactly which file to delete and replace

> --- the error:
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:225)
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:155)
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:169)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)emphasized
> text
> [!] Gradle threw an error while trying to update itself. Retrying the update...

How can I fix that.
Use the Android Studio release 3.6.1 .. flutter .. dart .. Windows

Comment: Reboot your system and then execute a `gradlew clean` in the project directory.

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually thrown when the gradle build that you're using is corrupted. To solve this issue, you can try modifying the gradle version that you're using. Look for gradle version that could work with your build on [this page](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/), and update gradle distributionUrl defined in gradle-wrapper.properties located on `/android/gradle/wrapper`. Then rebuild the Flutter project again with `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 0):

try running it with sudo, if that works then it means you have a problem with permission, change the owner of the flutter folder from root to you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).